# Как добавить скрытое поле или свой атрибут к элементу WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Можно ли как-то добавить к элементу скрытое поле или свой атрибут, для сохранения дополнительных данных? Нужно это для навигации в приложении - пользователь щелкает по одному из заказов и его перенаправлют на другую страницу, которая формируется на основе id заказа. Так вот это id надо как-то передать, а точнее связать с видимым элементом.

Comment: Чем наследование не угодило?

Comment: @AlexKrass не вопрос - покажите как сделать и как вставить потом это в xaml разметку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Если лень, можно использовать кнопки и их атрибут Tag для хранения значения.
2. Можно унаследоваться от элемента и добавить ему нужное свойство.

К примеру есть модель:

```
public class SomeModel 
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

Просто наследуясь от элемента, добавляем свойство.

```
class LinkSimle : Label
{
    public SomeModel LinkData { get; set; }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        MessageBox.Show("id: " + this.LinkData.ID + ", name: " + this.LinkData.Name);
    }
}
```

Можно даже в виде свойства зависимости.

```
class Link : Label
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LinkDataProperty;
    public SomeModel LinkData
    {
        set { SetValue(LinkDataProperty, value); }
        get { return (SomeModel)GetValue(LinkDataProperty); }
    }

    static Link() 
    {
        LinkDataProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.Register("LinkData", typeof(SomeModel), typeof(Link));
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        MessageBox.Show("id: " + this.LinkData.ID + ", name: " + this.LinkData.Name);
    }
}
```

Объявление в XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="APTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:myNamespace"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <my:Link MouseDown="Link_MouseDown" Content="Мопед">
            <my:Link.LinkData>
                <my:SomeModel ID="1" Name="Мопед" ></my:SomeModel>
            </my:Link.LinkData>
        </my:Link>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 3):

Вероятно, вас интересуют [Attached Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms749011%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). С их помощью можно добавлять свои свойства любому `DependencyObject`, в том числе прямо в XAML.

Если нужно добавлять свойства вообще любым объектам, то можно воспользоваться [ConditionalWeakTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Но в XAML этим воспользоваться не получится напрямую.

Answer (score 1):

Вы делаете неправильно, вам не должно такого хотеться. Дополнительные данные должны быть не в XAML, а в ViewModel. Отделяйте контент от представления! (И обязательно почитайте про MVVM.)

```
public class OrderVM : NotifyPropertyChangedImpl
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { if (name == value) return; name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}
```

и на стороне представления

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

Comment: А можно объяснить, что такое `NotifyPropertyChangedImpl`, и  каким образом я достану ID при клике на надпись?

Comment: @RussCoder: `NotifyPropertyChangeImpl` — это типичная имплементация базового класса для `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Например, такая: http://pastebin.com/hMBSH8HM.

Comment: @RussCoder: Типичная архитектура для таких случаев вот какая. (вариант 1) У вас есть `public ObservableCollection<OrderVM> Orders { get; set; }` и dependency property `OrderVM CurrentOrder`. Вы привязываете их к `ItemsSource` и `SelectedItem` какого-нибудь `ItemsControl`'а. При активизации от пользователя (например, нажатии на кнопку) срабатывает команда, которая навешена из VM через `Binding`. Эта команда смотрит на `CurrentOrder` и работает с ним. (Вам даже не нужен `Id`.)

Comment: @RussCoder: (вариант 2) У каждой `OrderVM` есть команда, которая мапится на метод `Activate`. Нажатие на что-то во View для `OrderVM` запускается команда из этого `OrderVM`, то есть запускается метод в нужной `OrderVM`. Опять-таки `Id` для связи не нужен.